# How to say the conjunction “now that” in Geman?

Tags: phrase-request, conjunction

If I want to say something like:

> Now that I have all the files, I can start working.
>
> How much money is left on my account, now that I paid for all that stuff?

How do I say this *now that* in German?

I instinctively want to use *nun dass* or *jetzt dass,* but when I search for these phrases, I don’t find them being used like that.

---

**Edit:** Google Translate suggests *nachdem*. This is not what I am looking for, because it expresses a temporal relation, and I am looking for a more causal relation. Example:

> *Where can I still go, now that I don't have a car anymore?*

The suggestions from [dict.cc](https://www.dict.cc/?s=now%20that) (*jetzt, wo* and *nun, da*) may perhaps be better. However, this is not obvious to me, since they require the comma between the two words (and thus the *jetzt* or *nun* in the main clause). Does this work with the examples I gave? And does it work without changing the meaning? If yes, please show me how, and please confirm that the meaning is the same as the English sentences.

Comment: what do you find while searching for now that or nun dass?

Comment: @ShegitBrahm Typically sentences with "nun, dass", example: "Ich weiß nun, dass es Hochmut war." I guess Google is really bad for searching punctuation proof

Comment: @LuKas: while google translate is only a rough guess for this purpose, I cannot tell you a better one than learning books. Please add your question clarification into your question to make it better. And what you still miss from trivial dictionaries for your understanding.

Comment: @ShegitBrahm I might have read your comment too fast. I meant searching phrase "nun das" in Google (not Translate) mostly shows sentences like "i know now, that it is wrong", which is not what I am looking for, as you can see from the examples. Using Google Translate for "now that" returns "nun das", which I think is not correct (perhaps I'm wrong?). In the translation of the full sentence is gives "nachdem", which is correct, but not what I'm looking for, because it is gives a temporal relation whereas I would prefer more a causal one.

Comment: @infinitezero I guess I should have gone immediately to dict.cc as the suggestions are much better, but Google did not lead me to it as a result. Nonetheless, it is still not clear to me if "jetzt, wo" or "nun, da" can simply replace "now that" in the example sentences.

Comment: @LuKas: thanks for the clarification, and please put it into your question. E.g. the causal relation and stuff. Otherwise it will get closed soon because of dictionary replacement. And need a reopening afterwards.

Comment: Der Schluss "and thus the jetzt or nun in the main clause" ist unmotiviert. Nebenbei ist DeepL auch eine gute Übersetzungshilfe.

Comment: @userunknown To me it doesn't seem obvious how to use those dictionary entries in a sentence. And none of all those in the comments saying it is just in the dictionary gave any example of how to. I can't see how anyone can claim that it is obvious to use two commas (", jetzt, wo"). But it seems like many on here know better ... Moreover, David Voigt updated his answer after my edit, and gave the answer I was looking for (so the closing is irrelevant anyway). Nebenbei, I had no knowledge of DeepL and I doubt it is very commonly known.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A close to literal translation would a temporal adverb such as *jetzt* or *nun* introducing a dependent clause with a subordinating conjunction *da* or *wo*.

> **Jetzt, wo** ich alle Unterlagen vorliegen habe, kann ich loslegen.
>   **Nun, da** ich alle Unterlagen vorliegen habe …

Note however that it is possible to move the temporal adverb into the subordinate clause. Other temporal adverbs such as *mittlerweile* or *inzwischen* are also acceptable or the temporal adverb might be left out. If the subordinate clause is in first position, I would prefer *da* over *wo*.

> **Da** ich **(jetzt/inzwischen/mittlerweile)** alle Unterlagen vorliegen habe …

The meaning of these subordinating conjunctions oscillates between temporal and causal (*post hoc ergo propter hoc*). *Nachdem* shares this temporal-causal double meaning and therefore also fits.

> **Nachdem** ich **nun also** alle Unterlagen vorliegen habe …

For the second sentence with the postponed subordinate clause I prefer *wo* or *nachdem* over *da*.

> Wieviel Geld ist denn noch auf dem Konto, **wo** ich das **jetzt** alles bezahlt habe?
>   … **nachdem** ich das **jetzt** alles bezahlt habe?

The temporal adverb with its dependent clause can also be postponed. However, this belongs more to spoken than written language.

> Wieviel Geld ist denn noch auf dem Konto, **jetzt, wo** ich das alles bezahlt habe?

Comment: Would it be possible in the second example to use it as _"Wieviel Geld ist d̶e̶n̶n̶  noch auf dem Konto jetzt, wo ich das alles bezahlt habe?"_ or _"Wieviel Geld ist noch auf dem Konto nun, da ich das alles bezahlt habe?"_ Or does that change the meaning? The conjugation I'm looking for is more causal than temporal, so _nachdem_ is not really what I'm looking for.

Comment: Both [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/nachdem) and [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/nachdem) agree that *nachdem* can have a causal meaning, although they classify it as regional.

Comment: @LuKas *denn* is completely optional. But Germans love their [Modalpartikeln](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modalpartikel); your sentences will sound more idiomatic if *ja, bloß, nur, doch, denn, halt, mal* etc. are used appropriately. *Jetzt wo* is fine as well.

Comment: That last edit seems to be what I was going for. But is that really correct with the two commas? The Germans seem to love their commas as well. ;)

Answer (score -3):

You could say:

- Jetzt habe ich alle Akten und kann anfangen zu arbeiten.
- Wieviel Geld ist noch auf meinem Konto, nachdem ich jetzt für all diese Sachen bezahlt habe?.

It is maybe a bit simpler in German.

Comment: Your first sentence translates to "Now I have all my files and can start working", which is different to "Now that I have all my files, I can start working".

Comment: "Now that" is translated using "Nun, da [...]" or "Jetzt, wo [...]". Neither of your examples stays true to the original.

Comment: I am not really looking for translations of these sentences, they are merely examples to show the meaning of the actual word/phrase I am looking for, namely "now that". Your suggestions circumvent this conjunction. (I didn't downvote however)

Comment: Yes, I think the literal translations sounds clumsy.